# Gradle project sync failed in Android studio3.1.3- WIndows 10

Tags: java, android, android-gradle-plugin

I'm trying to create an Android Studio project on my Windows 10 and I'm running some errors with the Android.mk file.
the *ffmpeg* folder is not in the Sdk folder and I do not understand why. I'm using the default SDK location. What's wrong?

SDK: C:\Users\danilo\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk

JDK: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre

NDK: C:\Users\danilo\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk-bundle

**Android.mk**:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
CVROOT:= C:\Users\danilo\Desktop\appandroid\OpenCV-android-sdk\sdk\native\jni
OPENCV_LIB_TYPE:=STATIC
include $(CVROOT)/OpenCV.mk
# Path to ffmpeg
# Has to be built and Android.mk written (libavformat, libavcodec, libavutil, libswscale needed)
# See https://enoent.fr/blog/2014/06/20/compile-ffmpeg-for-android/
FFMPEG_PATH := ../../../../sources/ffmpeg-2.2.3/android/arm

# Path to OpenCV
# http://sourceforge.net/projects/opencvlibrary/files/opencv-android/3.1.0/OpenCV-3.1.0-android-sdk.zip/download
OPENCV_PATH := C:\Users\danilo\Desktop\appandroid\OpenCV-android-sdk

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := FFmpegEncoder
LOCAL_LDLIBS := -llog -ljnigraphics -lz -landroid
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES += $(FFMPEG_PATH)/include
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := FFmpegEncoder.cpp com_prouast_heartbeat_FFmpegEncoder.cpp
LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES := libavformat-55 libavcodec-55 libavutil-52 libswscale-2
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
OPENCV_INSTALL_MODULES:=on
include $(OPENCV_PATH)/sdk/native/jni/OpenCV.mk
LOCAL_MODULE := RPPG
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := RPPG.cpp opencv.cpp com_prouast_heartbeat_RPPG.cpp
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES += $(LOCAL_PATH)
LOCAL_LDLIBS := -llog -ldl
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)

include $(FFMPEG_PATH)/Android.mk
```

**log file**:

```
Build command failed.


Error while executing process C:\Users\danilo\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk-bundle\ndk-build.cmd with arguments {NDK_PROJECT_PATH=null APP_BUILD_SCRIPT=C:\Users\danilo\Desktop\appandroid\heartbeat-android-master\app\src\main\jni\Android.mk NDK_APPLICATION_MK=C:\Users\danilo\Desktop\appandroid\heartbeat-android-master\app\src\main\jni\Application.mk APP_ABI=armeabi-v7a NDK_ALL_ABIS=armeabi-v7a NDK_DEBUG=1 APP_PLATFORM=android-15 NDK_OUT=C:/Users/danilo/Desktop/appandroid/heartbeat-android-master/app/build/intermediates/ndkBuild/debug/obj NDK_LIBS_OUT=C:\Users\danilo\Desktop\appandroid\heartbeat-android-master\app\build\intermediates\ndkBuild\debug\lib APP_SHORT_COMMANDS=false LOCAL_SHORT_COMMANDS=false -B -n}


Android NDK: WARNING: APP_STL gnustl_shared is deprecated and will be removed in the next release. Please switch to either c++_static or c++_shared. See https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/cpp-support.html for more information.    


process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, "", ...) failed.


../../../../sources/ffmpeg-2.2.3/android/arm/Android.mk: No such file or directory
Open File


Android NDK: Module FFmpegEncoder depends on undefined modules: avformat-55 avcodec-55 avutil-52 swscale-2    
Open File


*** Android NDK: Aborting (set APP_ALLOW_MISSING_DEPS=true to allow missing dependencies)    .  Stop.
Open File


Build command failed.


Error while executing process C:\Users\danilo\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk-bundle\ndk-build.cmd with arguments {NDK_PROJECT_PATH=null APP_BUILD_SCRIPT=C:\Users\danilo\Desktop\appandroid\heartbeat-android-master\app\src\main\jni\Android.mk NDK_APPLICATION_MK=C:\Users\danilo\Desktop\appandroid\heartbeat-android-master\app\src\main\jni\Application.mk APP_ABI=armeabi-v7a NDK_ALL_ABIS=armeabi-v7a NDK_DEBUG=0 APP_PLATFORM=android-15 NDK_OUT=C:/Users/danilo/Desktop/appandroid/heartbeat-android-master/app/build/intermediates/ndkBuild/release/obj NDK_LIBS_OUT=C:\Users\danilo\Desktop\appandroid\heartbeat-android-master\app\build\intermediates\ndkBuild\release\lib APP_SHORT_COMMANDS=false LOCAL_SHORT_COMMANDS=false -B -n}


Android NDK: WARNING: APP_STL gnustl_shared is deprecated and will be removed in the next release. Please switch to either c++_static or c++_shared. See https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/cpp-support.html for more information.    


process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, "", ...) failed.


../../../../sources/ffmpeg-2.2.3/android/arm/Android.mk: No such file or directory
Open File


Android NDK: Module FFmpegEncoder depends on undefined modules: avformat-55 avcodec-55 avutil-52 swscale-2    
Open File


*** Android NDK: Aborting (set APP_ALLOW_MISSING_DEPS=true to allow missing dependencies)    .  Stop.
Open File
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to link correctly C++ files to an existing Android Project in Android Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51988969/how-to-link-correctly-c-files-to-an-existing-android-project-in-android-studio)

Comment: @Bruno I'm running into different errors

Comment: *> ffmpeg folder is not in the Sdk folder and I do not understand why*  – **ffmpeg** is not part of Android SDK, or of OpenCV SDK. More, if you look at the [comment](https://github.com/prouast/heartbeat-android/blob/master/app/src/main/jni/Android.mk#L5) in the **Android.mk** file, it says that the ffmpeg libraries must be built separately.